# A beginner' question about RejectedExecutionException in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I begin to learn concurrency based on Java, I run the following code on windows (jdk 11)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class TaskWithResult implements Callable<String>{
      private int id;
      public TaskWithResult(int id){
        this.id = id;
      }
      public String call(){
        return  "Result of TaskWithResult "+id;
      }
    }

    public class TestCallable{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ArrayList<Future<String>> results = 
          new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
          results.add(exec.submit(new TaskWithResult(i)));
        for(Future<String> fs:results){
          try{
            System.out.println(fs.get());
          }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
          }catch(ExecutionException e){
            System.out.println(e);
          }finally{
            exec.shutdown();
          }
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

The sanme Exception occurs everytime I run it：

```
\\output：
Result of TaskWithResult 0
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@380fb434[Not completed, task = me.rexjz.a.TaskWithResult@21bcffb5] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3cda1055[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at javaBin/me.rexjz.a.TestCallable.main(TestCallable.java:22)
```

The code is excerpted from *Thinging in Java*(4th)，I initially guess the implicit thread which drives main() execute `shutdown()` before all the tasks are submitted because the first task is succeessfully executed and the Exeception information indicates that `pool size= 1`, but it is impossible because everything in main() is sequentially executed. All the Callable objects should be submitted before shutdown.

Then I change the type of ThreadPool to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`, the Exception stil occured and the pool size is still 1.

How did this happen?

Comment: There is a small issue in your code. Find the fixed code below.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your `for` loops a little more closely you'll see the problem (especially once the code is conventionally indented):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  results.add(exec.submit(new TaskWithResult(i)));
  for (Future<String> fs : results) {
    try {
      System.out.println(fs.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      exec.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the `for` loop which queries each `Future` is *nested* within the `for` loop which submits the tasks. That means you submit one task, wait for the result, *shutdown the executor*, and then attempt to submit another task. The following should fix your problem:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  results.add(exec.submit(new TaskWithResult(i)));
}

executor.shutdown(); // shutdown() allows already-submitted tasks to execute

for (Future<String> fs : results) {
  try {
    System.out.println(fs.get());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I moved the `executor.shutdown()` call since that only needs to happen once, after you've submitted the last task. Of course, if you're going to keep reusing the executor then you would not want to shut it down.

I also changed `System.out.println(e)` to `e.printStackTrace()`. It's typically better to print the stack trace rather than just the exception type and message (which is what `Throwable#toString()` returns, by default). It may not be obvious in a short program like your example, but the stack trace is extremely valuable in more complicated applications since it points you directly to where the exception was thrown. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.springboot.testapplication;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class TaskWithResult implements Callable<String> {
    private int id;

    public TaskWithResult(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String call() {
        return "Result of TaskWithResult " + id;
    }
}

public class TestCallable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ArrayList<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            results.add(exec.submit(new TaskWithResult(i)));
        }
        for (Future<String> fs : results) {
            try {
                System.out.println(fs.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return;
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                exec.shutdown();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write invokeAny() or invokeAll() methods before shutDown() or awaitTermination().

```
 Integer result  = executorService.invokeAny(futureList);
 System.out.println(result);
 executorService.shutdown();
```